# Modern OpenGL Versions?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I have sorta learned the old OpenGL (OpenGL 1.1) stuff but a lot of people say it's slow. So I've been wondering if anyone knows a good speed and compatibility (with older computers) version of OpenGL and where to learn it. I was thinking about OpenGL 3. Anyone have an idea on which OpenGL and if possible a link on the basics?

Comment: OpenGL 3.2, its called the Core Profile on Mac OS X. It completely removes fixed pipeline into a clean slick piece of awesome.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with the [LWJGL wiki](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) and their OpenGL 3.2 samples ([basic quad using VBOs/VAOs](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_with_DrawArrays))? (since you mentioned OpenGL 3). Some code may look weird; looks like they wanted to retain the origin of the function:

```
public void loopCycle() {
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Bind to the VAO that has all the information about the quad vertices
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

The site also explains the why of using VBOs, but there are more issues really when switching to a newer OpenGL version; e.g. they discuss shaders on [another page](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=The_Quad_colored).

Answer (score -1):

On compatibility: Nvidia supports OpenGL 3.0 on every card from the GeForce 8000 series upwards (which came out in 2008). And that's mostly the limit because that are the oldest cards which are supported by their current driver.

For newer versions than 3.0, compatibility drops. For example both my Nvidia NVS 4200M (in 2 year old business laptop) and my Intel i7 Sandy Bridge integrated graphics only support OpenGL up to version 3.0.

Starting with OpenGL 3.0 (with set forwards compatibility flag) the api closely resembles OpenGL-ES (the mobile version of OpenGL), so this is very handy if you ever do anything on the mobile market (e.g. developing for Android or iOS).

On learning: I upgraded my OpenGL knowledge from OpenGL 2.0 by reading the official OpenGL wiki (which is pretty good): http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Main_Page